# How to replicate OutOfMemory in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

The app I'm working on went through a testing process with physical devices. The testing team reported that

> Huawei P8 Lite Android 5.1: If an image of more than 4MB is uploaded, the application closes unexpectedly

I tried to replicate the issue with a "Google Pixel 3a with Android 5.1" emulator, but the process went ok. The code for this upload process include a resizing method so that no matter the image you choose, it won't be >4MB when it reaches the server.
I need to either reproduce the error and find a way to fix the issue or do something to the code that prevents such a crash (we believe it's an Out Of Memory crash) no matter how old the device is.
We're supporting Android 21+

```
private fun resize(image: Bitmap, maxWidth: Int, maxHeight: Int): Bitmap {
        var imageResized = image
        if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
            val width = imageResized.width
            val height = imageResized.height
            val ratioBitmap = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
            val ratioMax = maxWidth.toFloat() / maxHeight.toFloat()

            var finalWidth = maxWidth
            var finalHeight = maxHeight
            if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) {
                finalWidth = (maxHeight.toFloat() * ratioBitmap).toInt()
            } else {
                finalHeight = (maxWidth.toFloat() / ratioBitmap).toInt()
            }
            imageResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageResized, finalWidth, finalHeight, true)
            return imageResized
        } else {
            return imageResized
        }
    }

    fun captureImageResult(requestCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
        data?.data?.let {
            mCapturedImageURI = data.data
        }
    }


    mCapturedImageURI.let {
        val msm = MediaStorageManager((view as NewBaseFragment).activity!!)
        val bmp = msm.getBitmapFromUri(mCapturedImageURI!!)

        //save image bytes
        imageBytes = msm.getBytesFromBitmap(bmp!!)

        val bitmapScaled = resize(bmp, 1024, 1024)
        imageBytes = msm.getBytesFromBitmap(bitmapScaled)

        //image too big
        if (imageBytes?.size ?: IMAGE_MAX_SIZE < IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            //show image selected
            view.renderImage(bitmapScaled)
        } else {
            view.showErrorDialog()
            imageBytes = null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add this into your menifest  android:largeHeap="true"